# Finding the center of a responsive page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a googly eye that follows your mouse movements. I've been able to center the googly and listen for mouse movements, but I'm having trouble finding the center of the page after I've resized it.

```
var DrawEye = function(eyecontainer, pupil, eyeposx, eyeposy){
// Initialise core variables
 var r = $(pupil).width()/2;
 var center = {
  x: $(eyecontainer).width()/2 - r, 
  y: $(eyecontainer).height()/2 - r
 };
 var distanceThreshold = $(eyecontainer).width()/2.2 - r;
 var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

 // Listen for mouse movement
 $(window).mousemove(function(e){ 
   var d = {
   x: e.pageX - r - eyeposx - center.x,
   y: e.pageY - r - eyeposy - center.y
  };
  var distance = Math.sqrt(d.x*d.x + d.y*d.y);
  if (distance < distanceThreshold) {
   mouseX = e.pageX - eyeposx - r;
   mouseY = e.pageY - eyeposy - r;
  } else {
   mouseX = d.x / distance * distanceThreshold + center.x;
   mouseY = d.y / distance * distanceThreshold + center.y;
 }
});

// Update pupil location
var pupil = $(pupil);
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
  // change 1 to alter damping/momentum - higher is slower
  xp += (mouseX - xp) / 5;
  yp += (mouseY - yp) / 5;
  pupil.css({left:xp, top:yp});    
 }, 1);
};

var pariseye1 = new DrawEye("#eyeleft", "#pupilleft", 650, 300);
```

I'm trying to get it to follow the mouse no matter how big or small the window size is, I'm just having trouble figuring that out.

As of right now, if you resize the page the googly eye still follows the mouse, but it becomes slight ajar and doesn't quite follow the mouse exactly. It seems like where it's actually tracking the mouse stays the same.

I'm fairly new to javascript, so if anyone could help that would be great!

Thanks, James

Comment: `$(window).on('resize', function () {/*... your staff*/})`

Comment: Can you post this on codepen or jsfiddle? My guess is that you will need to call `DrawEye` again, or update it's position when the browser resizes.

Comment: Hmm, I added it into code pen and it just totally stopped working --> https://codepen.io/Marshall-James/pen/OzLENe

Comment: You forgot to load jQuery. Here is an codepen with jQuery and the `$(window).on('resize')`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEYaLP

Comment: Seems closer, but it's still slightly off when resizing the window.